# how to make a path not DEPRECATED

Tags: android, cordova, gradle

So im currenctly on a internship building a app using cordova (never used it before) and i keep running at this error:

```
C:\\Users\\utilizador\\Desktop\\escola\\estagio\\app freguesia\\www\>cordova compile android

Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions

ANDROID_HOME=C:\\Users\\utilizador\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools (recommended setting)

ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\\Users\\utilizador\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\build-tools (DEPRECATED)

Using Android SDK: C:\\Users\\utilizador\\AppData\\Local\\Android\\Sdk\\tools

Subproject Path: CordovaLib

Subproject Path: app

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 3 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
```

i already tried to mess a bit with the paths but it always stays deprecated and never compiles.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.